# How to solve 'Reference to an object not set on an object instance.'?

Tags: c#, winforms

In child form I have

```
public Print()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

public Print(int param)
        {
            this.se.EditValue = param;
        }
```

and I call it from another form :

```
private void function
{
     int value = GetValue();//it gets an int value
            if (value > 0)
            {
                using (Print printForm = new Print(value))
                ...
}
```

I am getting error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Reference to an object not set on an object instance.'
How can I fix it?

Comment: Only one constructor is ever called (directly) via `new`. If you want to initialize the UI components, then you also need to call `InitializeComponent()`. Perhaps you could call the parameterless constructor from the `int param` one using `this`? Something like  `public Print(int param) : this()` ?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of that question imo.  The issue here is to do with constructors as pointed out by Llama

Comment: @Martin it is a duplicate because literally every null reference exception is solved the same way; by debugging your code and finding what is null, and then fixing that. In this case it is indeed because the parameterless constructor was not called.

Comment: @Jamiec I've seen a lot of quetions with same error, but I couldn't figure it out ...

Comment: @ati It's a skill you'll learn as time goes on. But for the most part theyre impossible to answer without stepping through your code (This was a much simpler example)